# Samsung SVG audio format (of old voice pens, like SVR M920)

Tags: media-converter, file-format

The problem is, that I have got a voice pen recording in *.SVG format.
All I know is that it was recorded long ago and no CD with orginal voice pen software is available to find. Also there is no device itself - only the recording.

After some googling I found out:
 1. This recording must have been done with some old Samsung voice pen
 2. The software name, that might help to play or convert the recording must be "Voice Manager Pro M92x/M93x" of something like that
 3. The software from official Samsung site, that is named "Voice Manager" or "JetVoiceMail" is unable to play *.svg recordings - only *.cvf that I don't need
 4. The official site of SIMS voice pens http://simsvalley.com now is useless - there is hosted a hotel agency
 5. archive.org did manage to find the old version of simsvalley.com but not all the pages were stored, so there can be found no help too.
 6. http://voicepen.narod.ru/download.html seems to be a perfect solution, but not a single link is alive

Any ideas what can I try?
Maybe somebody can share that software with me?

Comment: could you open the file in an HEX editor and post the top 10 rows? Maybe it has a strange filename ending but a common format. Such could be seen in the file heading.

Comment: Also, a more precise information on "long ago" could help as we then could narrow down the possible formats to thoose that were availeable then (alternatevly post the date the pen stopped shipping or something)

Comment: SVG files, at least in today's world, are associated with images (SVG standing for Scalable Vector Graphics).  I've never heard of that as an audio format.  This may sound silly, but try creating a copy and rename the extention to MP3 or WAV.  Windows might just have a codec that will play the file if it finds a suitable extention.

Comment: Could you post the smallest of these files? Or is there any sample online already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally solved [here](https://superuser.com/questions/739002/samsung-svg-audio-format-of-old-voice-pens-like-svr-m920/740733#740733).
The required software is named, as was guessed, "Voice Manager Pro".
Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and download the [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/).
There you just open the file and hope for the best. If it is, as I would suspect, a regular sound file with an obsurue filename extension then your chances of opening the file through VLC is high.

But if it is some internal format that has been specifically developed for this machine then you might be lost.